# Get phone number Windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

**hello
how to get the phone number on windows phone 8.1 c# or VB.net.
thanks**

Comment: You can't for privacy reasons.

Comment: Asking it out... maybe a movie and a dinner...

Comment: **flowers. definitely flowers.**

Answer (score 2):

Not possible with the current SDK.

Answer (score 1):

You will need special permissions to get this information. Usually MSFT will release this information to partners only.

Answer (score 0):

Becaus its not posible, but.. If you need the phone number for some rezon...why don't you let the user enter it.like you need to do with what's app.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do something like that. It is a technical limitation from Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible , you need to ask the user the number of it ,like Whatsapp.